# Recylerview (with lots of items) in NestedScrollview get crashed Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have Recyclerview in NestedScrollView. Now I have 1000 of items to be populate in Recylerview but its showing UI is working too much work on its main thread and continuously gets crashed or asked for wait message.Any sugggestion would be appreciated.

```
    UI:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/view_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">


                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                            android:id="@+id/recylerview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>



//List Item:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/view_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_img"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_wextra"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rl_bg"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:maxHeight="30dp"
                android:maxWidth="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/pb_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pb_size"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="visible"

                />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/frwd_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/frwd_size"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_next" />


        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"

            android:textColor="@color/item_heading"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"

            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"

            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_btns"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ll_btns"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_loc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_img"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"

                    android:textColor="@color/text_heading_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"

                    android:textColor="@color/text_heading_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"

                    android:textColor="@color/text_heading_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"

                    android:textColor="@color/text_heading_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"

                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="0000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_userdes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"

                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="0000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_usernum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="0000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_userrating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="0000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


    Code:

         recylerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recylerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recylerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            recylerview.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
            ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getActivity(), R.dimen.item_offset_mini);
            recylerview.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);


    recylerview.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

//Adapter
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ItemModel item);
    }

    private List<ItemModel> items;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;


    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<ItemModel> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.bind(items.get(i), listener);


        viewHolder.tv_title.setText(items.get(i).getTitle());
        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(items.get(i).getItemTitle());
        viewHolder.tv_loc.setText(items.get(i).getItemLoc());
        viewHolder.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.tv_loc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        viewHolder.tv_userName.setText(items.get(i).getUserName());
        viewHolder.tv_userdes.setText(items.get(i).getUserDes());


        FragmentUtils.setBOLDFont(viewHolder.tv_title);
        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_name);
        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_loc);



        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_title_1);
        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_title_2);
        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_title_3);
        FragmentUtils.setFont(viewHolder.tv_title_4);

        // Loading profile image
        if (items.get(i).getImage().size() != 0) {

            Drawable myIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.not_found );
            ImageUtils.displayImageFromUrl(context, items.get(i).getImage().get(0).getThumbnail(), viewHolder.img,myIcon, new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@android.support.annotation.Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    viewHolder.pb_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    viewHolder.pb_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

        } else {
            ImageUtils.displayImageFromResources(context, viewHolder.img, R.drawable.not_found);
            viewHolder.pb_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        @BindView(R.id.tv_title)
        public TextView tv_title;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_name)
        public TextView tv_name;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_des)
        public TextView tv_des;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_userName)
        public TextView tv_userName;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_userLoc)
        public TextView tv_userLoc;



        @BindView(R.id.img)
        public ImageView img;

        @BindView(R.id.pb_img)
        public ProgressBar pb_img;


        @BindView(R.id.tv_title_1)
        public TextView tv_title_1;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_title_2)
        public TextView tv_title_2;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_title_3)
        public TextView tv_title_3;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_title_4)
        public TextView tv_title_4;


        public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

        public void bind(final ItemModel item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }

            });

        }
    }
}


///Log:

    01-23 10:14:19.343 11462-11467/com.app I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=241KB
    01-23 10:14:19.344 11462-11467/com.app I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
    01-23 10:14:19.344 11462-11467/com.app I/art: After code cache collection, code=213KB, data=181KB
    01-23 10:14:20.212 11462-11467/com.app I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=250KB, data=207KB
    01-23 10:14:20.213 11462-11467/com.app I/art: After code cache collection, code=250KB, data=207KB
    01-23 10:14:20.213 11462-11467/com.app I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
    01-23 10:14:27.706 11462-11462/com.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 505 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-23 10:14:35.519 11462-11462/com.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 464 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-23 10:14:43.019 11462-11462/com.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 449 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-23 10:14:50.488 11462-11462/com.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 447 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: are you using offset?

Comment: yes for spacing in items

Comment: If you have lots of data then you have to use handler class to bind data, Handler class will not stuck UI thread.

Comment: I am doing like that    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    recylerview.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                                }
                            });

Comment: please post your item layout as well

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: @farhana at that time it's not showing any error but this message "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: @NaveenDew please see my updated question

Comment: I think here is not necessary to use NestedScrollView ..you acheive your view only using recyclerview

Comment: if you are using offset then it will not have too much work in the main thread, When you scroll then data will upload, At a time it will not load 1000 record if your offset is of minimum range. I think this is not main thread problem.

Comment: could you pleas show your itemRecordAdapter?
that can change mush about the preformance

Comment: @fab see my updated code

Comment: are you using NestedScrollView for any specific purpse ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you have a `<RecyclerView>` tag with `wrap_content` for its height inside a `<NestedScrollView>`. This means that every single one of your 1000 items will have a viewholder created for it, causing thousands of views to be inflated and populated. I imagine that even if you wait for all of this to happen, your app will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

The obvious question is why you want to have a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. If you had this instead:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the RecyclerView would actually be able to perform view recycling and your app should become responsive.

Comment: I have a lot of information in my fragment in which I am showing/adding recylerview and want to scroll all screen with recylerview

Comment: @User42590 then you should use a fixed height for your RecyclerView tag. You *must* to use something other than `wrap_content` if you have a large number of items in the recycler

Answer (score 3):

Yes @Ben is correct your `RecyclerView` is `VERTICAL` and having `wrap_content` plus 1000 items there is no sense using it inside `NestedScrollView`

Try simply using `RecyclerView` inside `Relativelayout` or `Linearlayout`

also, I can see you have given `match_parent` to `ImageView` and again giving height in parent layout in this way the everytime its getting resize which is extra load in UI

also, note that `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` won't work with `match_parent`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_img"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_wextra"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rl_bg"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ll_info"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

One more thing it's better to use `placeholder` instead of `Progressbar` for `Imageview`.